# Make vertical border along with bullets using css pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

I want to make a list of elements look like this:

[image: Bullets with vertical line running along content]

Each main heading should have a bullet on its left and then a horizontal line. The horizontal line should connect to a vertical line and the vertical line should run along the length of the content. The content will be variable.

The vertical line of the preceding bullet should connect to the vertical line of the next bullet. 
The last bullet's content should not have a vertical line running along the content.

Here is what I have tried:

```css
.item-list {
  width: 100%;
}
.item-list .item {
  float: left;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.item-list .item .item-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.item-list .item .item-label:before {
  content: '\26AB';
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: -17px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-label">
      Bullet 1
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">Variable length text for bullet 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-label">
      Bullet 2
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">Variable length text for bullet 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-label">
      Bullet 3
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">Variable length text for bullet 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the result is:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve bullets with horizontal lines connected to a vertical border of the content and not break with content? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that?:

```css
.item-list {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.item-list .item {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.item-list .item:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}
.item-list .item:first-child:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}
.item-list .item:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -12px;
  width: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
.item-list .item .item-label {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0077cc;
}
.item-list .item .item-label:before {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
  left: -16px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #0077cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-label">
      Bullet 1
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">Variable length text for bullet 1<br>some more texte here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-label">
      Bullet 2
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">Variable length text for bullet 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-label">
      Bullet 3
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">Variable length text for bullet 3<br>second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andy. This is exactly what I want. Have to integrate this. If all works fine then will accept the answer, else will bother you to ask more. Upvoting for now :)